# Python bytearray with negative bytes

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I don't know anything about bytes. But, I have a Java application which I've developed to talk to my E-scooter.

I'm trying to write something similar on a Raspberry Pi, so I use Python. In the Java application, I have byte arrays that have negative numbers. For example:

```
byte[] array = new byte[90, -91, 0, 118, 57, 11...];
```

In Python, I get a "byte must be in range(0, 256) when trying to do this:

```
array = bytearray([90, -91, 0, 118, 57, 11...])
```

Anyone who could help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try -91 + 256 instead of -91, the binary code is same.

use (a + 256) % 256 to change negative to postive number.

-91 and 165 in 8 bit are the same in binary representation. [1010 0101]

```
array = bytearray([90, 165, 0, 118, 57, 11...])
```

Comment: How would this be if a had an array like this: bytearray([90, -91, 0, 118, 57, 11, 125, 34, 31, -122, -4, 0, 2])?

Comment: (a + 256) % 256 which a can be postive or negative number, this will change all negative to postive number in 8 bits.

Comment: and 'a' is? Sorry for asking dumb questions. How can I initialize the bytearray with that formula?

Comment: you can try this: bytearray([90, 165, 0, 118, 57, 11, 125, 34, 31, 134, 252, 0, 2])

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find these conversions?

Comment: 2's complement, refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228932/discussion-between-icejoywoo-and-basse).